# XSLT how to avoid to select nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Hi guys i want to apply my follwing nodes but there are two nodes which i won't select. How can I avoid do select 2 of the nodes but how can I concat my statement in the select . I use oxygen and xslt 2.0.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(local-name() = 'pc')] |
   *[not(local-name() = 'computer')]"/>
```

xml-file

```
 <a/>
  <b/>
  <pc/>
  <computer/>
  <a/>
  <b/>
  <c/>
```

and so on..

expected selected nodes ,, ,,,

Comment: Please show an example of your XML input (preferably minimized) and explain which nodes you want/don't want to select. -- In general, XPath 2.0 allows you to use the `except` operator: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-except -- Also in general: unless there are good reasons preventing you from doing so, you'd well advised to use namespaces when addressing nodes in the source XML, instead of local-name() only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression means "give me everything that is not a `pc` plus everything that is not a `computer`". Since a `pc` is not a `computer` and vice versa, each side of the `|` is selecting the nodes that the other side excluded and you end up with everything. You need to test both conditions against the same node to say "give me every element that is neither a `pc` nor a `computer`":

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(local-name() = 'pc')][not(local-name() = 'computer')]"/>
```

But since you're in XSLT 2.0 this can be expressed more succinctly using namespace wildcards and the `except` operator:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="* except (*:pc, *:computer)"/>
```

Depending what (if any) namespaces your document and stylesheet declare, you may not need the `*:` or you may be able to replace it with a fixed prefix to use namespaces properly rather than ignoring them.

Comment: Nice method 'EXCEPT', plus one.